# How to effectively use the counter variable to count the number of points?

Tags: java

I am creating a game of **wordguess*

Player1 inputs a mystery word and then the output is the number of letters in that word.

Then in a **while loop**, player2 guesses the words, and if they are not the mystery word, then a statement says **"the phrase is not a mystery word"**, **But** when player2 guesses the mystery word the following should be the output as shown in the print statements down below:

```
else if (phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
    go = false;
    counter--;
    int points = (mysteryphrase.length()*10-counter*5);
    System.out.println("Correct! The mystery word is"+mysteryphrase+".");
    System.out.println("You made "+counter+" incorrect guesses");
    System.out.println("You get "+points+" points");
```

I got it to work but then another requirement is that when it reaches the double of the mystery words length, then the game should stop and it should say the following:

```
else if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
    go = false;
    System.out.println("\n"+"You made "+counter2+" incorrect guesses");
    System.out.println("You get 0 points");
    System.out.println("You lost the game");
}
```

The problem I am facing is that there is a certain formula for calculating points which is:

```
Points = (number of letters in the word * 10 - incorrect guesses *5)
```

This works for when the game stops after double the mystery words length, but when player2 correctly guesses the mystery word, it does not work. Why is that?

For those interested this is my whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Wordguess{
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    String mysteryphrase = keyboard.next();
        System.out.print("The mystery word has "+mysteryphrase.length()+" letters"+".");
        if (option == 1){
            boolean go = true;
            while (go){
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    System.out.print("The mystery word is not "+phrase+".");
                }
                else if (phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    go = false;
                    System.out.print("Correct! The mystery word is "+mysteryphrase+".");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (option == 2){
            int counter = 1;
            boolean go = true;
            while (go){
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    System.out.print("The mystery word is not "+phrase);
                    counter++;
                }
                else if (phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    go = false;
                    counter--;
                    int points = (mysteryphrase.length()*10-counter*5);
                    System.out.println("Correct! The mystery word is"+mysteryphrase+".");
                    System.out.println("You made "+counter+" incorrect guesses");
                    System.out.println("You get "+points+" points");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (option == 3){
            int counter = 1;
            int counter2 = 0;
            boolean go = true;
            while (go){
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    System.out.print("The mystery word is not "+phrase);
                    counter++;
                    counter2++;
                }
                else if (phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
                    go = false;
                    counter--;
                    int points = (mysteryphrase.length()*10-counter*5);
                    System.out.println("Correct! The mystery word is"+mysteryphrase+".");
                    System.out.println("You made "+counter+" incorrect guesses");
                    System.out.println("You get "+points+" points");
                }
                else if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
                    go = false;
                    System.out.println("\n"+"You made "+counter2+" incorrect guesses");
                    System.out.println("You get 0 points");
                    System.out.println("You lost the game");
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I used two counters, one for the win and one for to check if the mystery words length doubles and the game ends. "counter" doesn't seem to work for points when player2 guesses correctly.

The following is my output which is incorrect for points:

```
You get 5 points
```

It should be let's say after players guesses correctly and after 5 guesses:

```
You get 70 points
```

Comment: Can you tell me where the user types the word? You parse the input directly into integer (at line 5)

Comment: Sorry yah i accepted your answer thanks, also this is my new account I was looking to ask you for help but I couldn't comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will never be executed in your program:

```
else if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
    go = false;
    System.out.println("\n"+"You made "+counter2+" incorrect guesses");
    System.out.println("You get 0 points");
    System.out.println("You lost the game");
}
```

The reason is when you check, `if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase))`, it will be either `true` or `false` and therefore an `else if` is not only meaningless but can also cause confusion and problem which you are facing.

## Correct program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter option: ");
        int option = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the mystery word: ");
        String mysteryphrase = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("The mystery word has " + mysteryphrase.length() + " letters.");
        if (option == 1) {
            boolean go = true;
            while (go) {
                System.out.print("Your word: ");
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)) {
                    System.out.println("The mystery word is not '" + phrase + "'.");
                } else {
                    go = false;
                    System.out.print("Correct! The mystery word is '" + mysteryphrase + "'.");
                }
            }
        } else if (option == 2) {
            int counter = 1;
            boolean go = true;
            while (go) {
                System.out.print("Your word: ");
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)) {
                    System.out.println("The mystery word is not " + phrase);
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    go = false;
                    counter--;
                    int points = mysteryphrase.length() * 10 - counter * 5;
                    System.out.println("Correct! The mystery word is '" + mysteryphrase + "'.");
                    System.out.println("You made " + counter + " incorrect guesses.");
                    System.out.println("You get " + points + " points.");
                }
            }
        } else if (option == 3) {
            int counter = 1;
            int counter2 = 0;
            boolean go = true;
            while (go) {
                System.out.print("Your word: ");
                String phrase = keyboard.next();
                if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)) {
                    System.out.println("The mystery word is not '" + phrase + "'.");
                    counter++;
                    counter2++;
                } else {
                    if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length() * 2) {
                        System.out.println("\n" + "You made " + counter2 + " incorrect guesses.");
                        System.out.println("You get 0 points");
                        System.out.println("You lost the game");
                        break;
                    }
                    go = false;
                    counter--;
                    int points = mysteryphrase.length() * 10 - counter * 5;
                    System.out.println("Correct! The mystery word is '" + mysteryphrase + "'.");
                    System.out.println("You made " + counter + " incorrect guesses.");
                    System.out.println("You get " + points + " points.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter option: 1
Enter the mystery word: hello
The mystery word has 5 letters.
Your word: hi
The mystery word is not 'hi'.
Your word: bye
The mystery word is not 'bye'.
Your word: hello
Correct! The mystery word is 'hello'.
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 2
Enter the mystery word: hello
The mystery word has 5 letters.
Your word: hi
The mystery word is not hi
Your word: bye
The mystery word is not bye
Your word: hello
Correct! The mystery word is 'hello'.
You made 2 incorrect guesses.
You get 40 points.
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
Enter the mystery word: hello
The mystery word has 5 letters.
Your word: hi
The mystery word is not 'hi'.
Your word: bye
The mystery word is not 'bye'.
Your word: hello
Correct! The mystery word is 'hello'.
You made 2 incorrect guesses.
You get 40 points.
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter option: 3
Enter the mystery word: hi
The mystery word has 2 letters.
Your word: hello
The mystery word is not 'hello'.
Your word: world
The mystery word is not 'world'.
Your word: bye
The mystery word is not 'bye'.
Your word: moon
The mystery word is not 'moon'.
Your word: hi

You made 4 incorrect guesses.
You get 0 points
You lost the game
```

Comment: I just saw your message. I can see that it has been answered and you've accepted it which means that you have got what you were looking for. Wish you success!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705204/the-following-code-is-correct-but-i-would-like-to-make-some-adjustments-java

Comment: @hussain123 - Please clean up the above message as it is not related to this Q/A. Also, do so for your comment below your question. Comments which are not related to the current Q/A should be removed as per the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters 3 as the *option*, you have the following code

```java
if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
```

Then you have

```java
else if (phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)) {
```

After which you have

```java
else if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
```

You will never enter the last `else if`. Either the word that the user enters is the mystery word or it is not. There is no third option. Perhaps you simply need to drop the last else and make it

```java
if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
```

### EDIT

Actually, you need to check the value of `counter2` immediately after each incorrect guess, so your initial condition should be

```java
if (!phrase.equals(mysteryphrase)){
    System.out.print("The mystery word is not "+phrase);
    counter++;
    counter2++;
    if (counter2 == mysteryphrase.length()*2){
        go = false;
        System.out.println("\n"+"You made "+counter2+" incorrect guesses");
        System.out.println("You get 0 points");
        System.out.println("You lost the game");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shorter and simpler code for your program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GFG{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the mystery word");
        String mystery=sc.nextLine();
        int counter=0;
        while(counter<mystery.length()*2){
            System.out.println("Guess the mystery word!");
            String guess=sc.nextLine();
            if(guess.equals(mystery))
                break;
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter==mystery.length()*2)
            System.out.println("You made "+counter+" incorrect guesses so your score is 0");
        int score=mystery.length()*10-counter*5;
        System.out.println("You made "+counter+" incorrect guesses and your score is "+score);
    }
}
```